# DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded in gcp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, postman, fastapi, http-status-code-504

Hello i use a Query in my fast_api code in order to get information from Firebase:

Thie code gives me the generator of  currentProjectsRef.collection('infoBorehole') of specific date.

```
infoBorehole = currentProjectsRef.collection('infoBorehole').where(u'dateExecution', u'>=', from).where(
            u'dateExecution', u'<=', to).stream()
```

Post Json looks

```
{
    "items": [
        {

            "from": "2023-09-01",
            "to": "2023-09-27"
        }
    ]
}
```

Everythings works fine with small couple of data. But when I give biger size of time for example "from": "2023-01-01" ,"to": "2023-09-27". It gives me server error 504. This also happen in local code and on when I run this on GCP

The rest of error on GCP console:
`DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded`
`_MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with`
`AttributeError: '_UnaryStreamMultiCallable' object has no attribute '_retry'

The errors in local code stuido via postman:

```
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
        details = "Deadline Exceeded"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.203.202:443 {grpc_message:"Deadline Exceeded", grpc_status:4, created_time:"2023-09-27T10:39:39.480990121+00:00"}"
>
`
```

Does anyone know what can i do?

As i above. i do not have idea whats is going on